# Character Rigging and Mesh Deformations rotating and shrinking strangely around joint

Tags: mesh, rigging, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

This time, I began to rig a mesh through weight painting and deformations so I could achieve an accurate effect to my liking. For all my characters before, I have used object rigging, (Without Vertex groups as I never needed to have some).

However, this time I have an arm with two bones, One for the forearm and one for the wrist. When I rotate the wrist, it works correctly, but once I rotate the forearm, there are a specific pair of circular vertices that work strangely.

Here is the weight paint and arm at rest position:
[image]

The Yellow and light blue ones deform once I rotate the bone.
[image]

Like so. 
It is strange because I have an armature modifier applied to the object with preserved volume checked. Yet it seems as if those sets of vertices do not follow the command; they seem to be moving closer and closer to the joint whilst shrinking as I rotate the bone.

Here is what the weight values of the second bone are:
[image]

Any suggestions or wisdom would be appreciated, and I can always upload the .blend if you ask me to.
Thank you.

Here is the .blend file: 
[image]

Comment: Could you provide your .blend file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you?

Comment: Added it for you

Comment: I'm confused what is the exact problem? Can you highlight it in the screenshots?

Comment: There are a set of vertices that continue to shrink towards the joint of the bone whenever it is moved. If you rotate it, you'll see them, I don't know how to fix them so that they follow the shoulder bone and have the appropriate relations to the wrist bone so they do not deform unnaturally.

Comment: Answer provided with screenshots, you can accept and upvote it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select your Mesh and delete all vertex groups and all modifiers as shown:
   [image]
   [image]
2. Select your Mesh then select your armature using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+RightClick and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then choose `With Empty Groups`:
   [image]
3. Switch to Pose Mode then select the two bones LWrist and LShoulder then select the mesh using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+RightClick as shown below:
   [image]
   [image]
4. Switch to weight painting mode and select `Assign Automatic From Bones` from the `Weights` menu as shown below:
   [image]

Done, now the mesh will have weights assigned to these bones with good deformations as shown below:

[image]